# Monitor Aurora using Datadog doesn't show changes in Query-volume

Tags: mysql, monitoring, metrics, amazon-aurora, datadog

I'm using [Datadog dashboard to monitor Aurora clusters](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-aurora-using-datadog/) I have in my account.

The "[query-volume](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-mysql-performance-metrics/#query-throughput)" section is always empty, even if I go the mysql shell and do a couple of selects.

I'd like to make sure it works before I put high load on my db in production.

for now I only see changes in query-volume section in the charts of `Select latency and DML latency` and in AWS resource metrics in all charts.
whereas DiskIO section is totally empty, ( Connection and Replication is empty as well, but I know that because I don't have a replica )

Any idea how can I make sure it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I had to install a Datadog agent on ec2 instance and configure it to be able to access all mysql dbs and collect the mysql performance schema metrics. And surely with correct security groups for the ec2.
I followed this [docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_rds/#native-database-integration-1) and [this](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-rds-mysql-performance-metrics/) and contacted the support.